# How to change font on PowerShell

Tags: powershell, windows-10

How do I change the font for PowerShell?

There are only a few kind of fonts in PowerShell Preference.

Is there a way to choose more fonts?

Comment: What do you mean by "change font on PowerShell"? Do you want to change the font used for the PowerShell console? Manually or programmatically?

Comment: I want to change font with profile.

Comment: I don't think it's possible to do that in a PoSh way for the current process, because it's a setting of the console host (`conhost.exe`), not the PowerShell host process. [Maybe related](http://serverfault.com/q/548103/134295).

Answer (score 7):

To change the font in PowerShell:

1. Right click on the PowerShell icon at the top left of the PowerShell screen
2. Click Properties
3. A window appears, showing options for font size, family, colors and more.

[image: Screenshot of PowerShell properties]

Comment: Unfortunately, this does not persist between launches

Comment: I did this on Windows 10.  Having trouble finding this on Windows 11.

Answer (score 4):

When you launch Powershell.exe, *client server runtime sub-system(csrss.exe)* spawns a child process called conhost.exe.

You can try this the harder way to deal with the font:

```
Set-Location HKCU:\Console
New-Item '.\%SystemRoot%_System32_WindowsPowerShell_v1.0_powershell.exe'
Set-Location '.\%SystemRoot%_System32_WindowsPowerShell_v1.0_powershell.exe'
New-ItemProperty . FaceName -type STRING -value "Lucida Console"
New-ItemProperty . FontFamily -type DWORD -value 0x00000036
New-ItemProperty . FontSize -type DWORD -value 0x000c0000
New-ItemProperty . FontWeight -type DWORD -value 0x00000190
```

Apart from that, there is a ***SetConsoleFont*** module available for PowerShell.

The cmdlet for setting it is:

```
Set-ConsoleFont 10
```

You can check [4SysOps](https://4sysops.com/archives/change-powershell-console-font-size-with-cmdlet/) for reference.

A few exports are there under **kernel32.dll** that can change the font also.

Answer (score 1):

Nowadays, at windows 11, you need to follow next steps:

1. Open PowerShell
2. Right click on the window top bar
3. Select **Settings**
4. You will see the scrolling bar on the left side with different tabs. Select PowerShell tab.
5. In **Additional settings** space select **Appearance**.
6. In the **Text** space you will find **Font size** setting.

[Settings window](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ySvyC.png)

[Appearance window](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lgmzH.png)

Answer (score 0):

I like the module [WindowsConsoleFonts](https://www.powershellgallery.com/packages/WindowsConsoleFonts) from `PSGallery` that has the following commands

```
Install-Module WindowsConsoleFonts

Get-Command -Module WindowsConsoleFonts

CommandType     Name                                    Version    Source
-----------     ----                                     -------    ------
Cmdlet          Add-Font                      1.1.0      WindowsConsoleFonts
Cmdlet          Get-ConsoleFont               1.1.0      WindowsConsoleFonts
Cmdlet          Remove-Font                   1.1.0      WindowsConsoleFonts
Cmdlet          Set-ConsoleFont               1.1.0      WindowsConsoleFonts
```